# How to display '...' in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my view:

```
= form @user do |f|
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.fields_for :addresses do |f|
  = render "addresses", f: f
```

And in my partial '_adresses.html.haml'

```
????????????
  =f.label :city
  =f.text_field :city
```

How can I place "NOT CHOSEN" in ???????? when my action is new, and name of city when my action is edit?

If I write:

```
= :city
```

It shows the word city, not name of city.

Comment: I'm not understand your question much, but you can check if `@user` is a new record (not saved in table) or not, you can use `@user.persisted?`, it return true if @user already is in table User.

Comment: OK, but i only need to display city name in partial _adresses. Not in field, but for example <h1>CITY NAME</h1> before city input field. It sholud be display in action edit, when address was added. If i render action new it should display <h1>NOT CHOOSEN<h1> before city input field.

Comment: you can do `if f.object.persisted? <h1> CITY NAME </h1> else <h1> NOT CHOOSEN <h1> end` in address partial.

Comment: In place CITY NAME i need real city name if it is rendered from action edit, something like this ????.city.name. What instead of ????

Comment: if you are in address partial, to get the name, put after :city, `f.object.city.name`

Comment: Big thanks f.object.city.name it is solution. Best regards

Comment: okay, so I will post it as answer, please accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if @user is a new record (not saved in table) or not, you can use @user.persisted?, it return true if @user already is in table User.

You can do:

```
if f.object.persisted? 
<h1> CITY NAME </h1> 
else 
<h1> NOT CHOOSEN <h1> 
end
```

in address partial. If you are in address partial, to get the name, put after :city, `f.object.city.name`